# threejs - customDepthMaterial property on mesh not included in scene.toJSON output

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have an object that I'm creating like so:

```
const geometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(2,100,100);
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    map: myImage
    transparent: true,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    opacity: 0.8
});

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

This material some transparency and I want only the *non-transparent* parts to cast a shadow so I add:

```
mesh.customDepthMaterial = new THREE.MeshDepthMaterial({
   depthPacking: THREE.RGBADepthPacking,
   alphaTest: 0.4,
   map: image
});
```

This renders just fine in the scene. If I inspect the scene, that customDepthMaterial property exists on the mesh.

But when I do `scene.toJSON()`, that property is not included on that mesh (and if I load that JSON into the scene, the transparency is lost because there is no customDepthMaterial).

Is this intended? Or a bug? Or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this intended? Or a bug? Or am I just doing something wrong?

You are doing everything right! The problem is that `three.js` does not yet support serialization/deserialization for `Object3D.customDepthMaterial` and `Object3D.customDistanceMaterial`.

I suggest you file a feature request at GitHub.

`three.js r122`